# Angular2: swap subcomponents

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to swap subcomponents using `ngIf` like:

```
<div *ngIf="paymentListShow" payment-list></div>
<div *ngIf="paymentFormShow" payment-form></div>
```

So, my parent component is intended to handle these values:

```
swapComponent(componentName: string): void {
    let paymentState = {
      'paymentList': (that): void => {
        that.paymentFormShow = false;
        that.paymentListShow = true;
      },

      'paymentForm': (that): void => {
        that.paymentListShow = false;
        that.paymentFormShow = true;
      }
    };

    paymentState[componentName](this);
}
```

Does it exist any more elegant way to swap subcomponents? Using rxjs Observables?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not the best, but this could be a cleaner way:

```
show = {
  paymentList: true,
  paymentForm: false
}

swapComponent(componentName: string): void {
  for (const component in this.show) {
    if (this.show.hasOwnProperty(component)) {
      this.show[component] = (component === componentName) ? true : false;
    }
  }
}
```

Combined with:

```
<div *ngIf="show.paymentList" payment-list></div>
<div *ngIf="show.paymentForm" payment-form></div>
```